# ¿Cómo generar código auto incrementable compuesto con año y mes actual en SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql-server

Necesito generar un código auto incrementable compuesto con los dos últimos dígitos del año, los dos dígitos del mes actual y mi auto incrementable.
Ejemplo:

- 2302001
- 2302002
- 2302003

Ya antes e creado una tabla con código auto incrementable de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE TABLE F_01S(
idNumParte INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
NumParte AS ('01S' + RIGHT('0000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, idNumParte),(4))),
Descripcion NVARCHAR(MAX),
Referencia NVARCHAR(500),
Unidad NVARCHAR(50),
SubEns NVARCHAR(10),
PrecioUSD MONEY,
PrecioMXN MONEY,
Observaciones NVARCHAR(MAX),
Revision NVARCHAR(2)
);
```

Pero ahora lo tengo que hacer la manera ya mencionada. Si me pueden ayudar estaría muy agradecida

Comment: El auto incrementable tiene que reiniciarse en cada mes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola para eso podrias usar el FORMAT DE SQL

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Con este te puedes ayudar para obtener los ultimos 2 digitos del año y los 2 del mes y ya luego solo concatenarle el identity con ayuda de un RIGHT para tomar el ID

Te anexo un ejemplo

```
DECLARE @DemoTable TABLE 
(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
NumParte AS FORMAT( GETDATE(), 'yyMM', 'en-US' )+RIGHT('000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, ID),(4)) ,
Descripcion VARCHAR(100)
)


INSERT INTO @DemoTable (Descripcion) VALUES('DESC 1')
INSERT INTO @DemoTable (Descripcion) VALUES('DESC 2')


SELECT * FROM @DemoTable
```

Aqui te dejo un ejemplo, donde puedes ver el codigo funcionando

https://dbfiddle.uk/zVvWBjc_

Edit
Por algun motivo el _ del link no lo reconoce para ver el demo solo agregale _ al final

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por leerme y por tu ayuda, Edgar. Me sirvió muchísimo

Comment: De nada, estamos para apoyar, Saludos

Comment: Hay que tener cuidado con la función `FORMAT()` es mucho más lenta (dicen que hasta 40 veces) que usar algo como `RIGHT( CONVERT( CHAR(6), GETDATE(), 112), 4)`.

Comment: Gracias  @LuisCazares lo tendre en cuenta